# JSON parser for Java online

Tags: java, android, json

Is there a Json - parser for java online that can help me to create Java - objects from Json-string? (I found similar one but there I can translate json-string in Java -objects only if I have url for my json-string)?

Comment: Can you post the link you found and an example of what you want to go in and come out of that conversion process?

Comment: http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the link, this should be easy:

- upload your JSON string to a site like [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)
- get the **RAW** link, i.e. the one without the PasteBin website around)
- put that into http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://jackson.codehaus.org/

But be sure that you really want to put it into Java objects, because whenever the JSON representation changes, translation will break of course.

Comment: I am using google-json and I need to know structure of json-string to create java entity objects(json string is to big in my case) - so I want to find online tool that can help me generate these objects.

Comment: Jackson is great, but this isn't answering the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

[QuickType.io](https://quicktype.io) is exactly what you're looking for.

For the record, I'm unaffiliated.